# JQuery: How to distinguish 404 from other types of error on image load

Tags: jquery, image, cross-domain, http-status-code-404

I need to test if a remote text file is simply present or not and wrapping it in JSONP is not an option. Also IE ignores any attempt to allow cross-domain AJAX access by default. One way to get around this I have read up on is to set it as the source of an image object and see if it generates an error.

```
img = $('<img />',{ src: '/myfile.txt'}).bind('error', function(returned) {console.dir(returned);})
```

This doesn't work because the text file is obviously not a valid image. But in this case the message displayed in the console is...

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml
```

If there is no file then the error displayed in the console is...

```
GET http://example.com/myfile.txt 404 (Not Found)
```

Both trigger an the error function if I bind to it but I can't see any way to distinguish which error of the two is being trapped. If I drill into the "returned" object I can see loads of stuff but no mention of the actual error message or the 404 code I am looking for. How to I get that information?